# Using Find Method on an already existing Find Method in Ruby showing NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As the question says, I am trying to use the `.find` Method but I am getting a `NoMethodError` for Nil Objects.

I understand that this is **normal behaviour** it makes sense, but is there anyway in which I could improve the code to avoid using the `.find` twice?

This is how my code looks currently:

> `@device = Device.find(:all).find{|device| device.uuid == @token.uuid}`

RubyMine is highlighting the second `.find` method:

> `.find{|device| device.uuid == @token.uuid}`

with a warning saying  :

> `Method invocation 'find' may produce 'NoMethodError'`

I realise this may not be the best way to go about this. Can anyone please help on suggestions? And maybe tell me whether by removing the second `.find()` I'd get the same results!

I kindly appreciate all answers.

Comment: `find(:all)` – that looks like [Rails 2.x syntax](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001788). Are you maintaining a very old codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
@device = Device.find(:all, :conditions => { :uuid => @token.uuid })
```